# Is it permissable to share photos of recognized brands as nonprofit art?

Tags: legal, copyright, fair-use

I have read few blogs on this question, but many of them contradict themselves, and even some admit that themselves as it is such a contradictional issue because there can be different use cases that may or may not permit such uses.

As an example I've taken a photo of a shelf full of bottles of recognized brands.

Am I permitted to post this picture on a social site like Flickr if it is with purely artistic intent and with no profit attached to it?

Comment: also have a look at this link -https://www.flickr.com/help/guidelines/

Comment: Interesting note about Warhol's use of Campbell's Soup can designs and trademarks.  http://clancco.com/wp/2010/08/warhol_copyright_campbells-soup/

Comment: Its not copyright you're at issue with for brands - its trademark (and thats a whole 'nother ball of wax).  You might want to consider reading up on specific legal handbooks for photographers on the matter from lawyers. The one I'd point to is [Legal Handbook for Photographers](http://www.amazon.com/Legal-Handbook-Photographers-Rights-Liabilities/dp/1608954757) ([author's web page](http://www.krages.com) - he's an attorney who concentrates on intellectual property law and is a photographer himself)

Answer (score 3):

This is a situation where any legal situation/case would be tested on it's merits and would depend entirely on the image.

In most jurisdictions if the arrangement of the products and their lighting show an artistic intent then you are in 'fair use' territory.  Even if that work is sold for profit.

In this situation it's probably better to ask forgiveness than permission.  The worst that might happen is flickr may get a complaint and they'll do what's cheapest (which will probably be pull the image rather than pay a lawyer to argue about it.)

Given the prior art on flickr ([flickr.com/search/?text=coke](https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=coke)) in anqphotography's comment, it's probably best to publish and be damned.